# How can i merge 2 duplicate Tables with different values?

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I want to consolidate 2 tables into one (table or view). Both have the exact columns, but diffent values, like:

Table 1:

```
id    Doc1             Doc2
---------------------------------
1     12/06/2016       NULL
2     20/08/2016       15/03/2016
3     NULL             NULL
```

Table 2:

```
id    name    desc
-----------------------
1     NULL      1
2     NULL      NULL
3     1         0
```

The logic I want to use is this:

If value on Table 1 is a date (not NULL) then 'YES'

If value on Table 1 is NULL, check Table 2

If value on Table 2 is 1 then 'NA'

If value on Table 2 is 0 or NULL then 'NO'

So the result table will be something like this:

Table Result:

```
id    Doc1    Doc2
-----------------------
1     YES      NA
2     YES      YES
3     NA       NO
```

How can I do this?

Comment: OK, so what is the logic now? it seems the new table will have string data type in the columns, with values Yes, NA and NO (and apparently no consistency in capitalization?) What's the rule - when do you get a Yes, when an NA, and when a NO - and when is it all caps as in YES and when is it Yes? Why is the third row in the result table (NA, NO)? In table 1 both are NULL, and in table 2 both are not NULL or NA, but they are treated differently - why?

Comment: Sorry, everything is captilized. My mistake there.

Comment: And the logic? (especially the different results in Doc1 and Doc2 for id=3).

Comment: And, wait, what do you mean by "NULL or NA" for values in table 2? If the columns are NUMBER, how can they hold NA?

Comment: The Logic is: If Table 1 value is a date(not NULL) then 'YES' If Table 1 value is NULL, check Table 2. If Table 2 value is 1 then 'NA' If Table 2 value is NULL or 0 then 'NO'

Comment: I edited again the question. I believe its a lot clear now

Comment: Yes, it is a lot clearer now - and the solution uses the more general `case` expression (of which `coalesce()` is a special case; `coalesce` doesn't make sense for the restated problem.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
select t1.id as id,
       case when t1.doc1 is not null then 'YES'
            when t2.name != 0        then 'NA'
                                     else 'NO' end as doc1,
       case when t1.doc2 is not null then 'YES'
            when t2.desc != 0        then 'NA'
                                     else 'NO' end as doc2
from table_1 t1 full outer join table_2 t2 on t1.id = t2.id
;
```

This takes advantage of the "short-circuit evaluation" of `case` expressions - the first `when` that evaluates to TRUE sets the value of the expression and the remaining branches (if any) are skipped. `!=0` implies `not null`, by the way.

Comment: What if the columns are in different types? The Table 1 values are DATEs and TABLE 2 values are Numbers.

Comment: Then the question makes no sense. How do you want to enter a number (from table 2) in a DATE column (from table 1) if the value in table 1 is NULL? You can't do that in a SELECT query, a new table, or a view. More importantly - you can't because it makes no sense (not because the technology is not advanced enough or similar reasons).

Comment: Changing both types. I edited the question so it looks like exactly what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Thx! The case expression is working perfectly. The only problem is that I don't think the full outer join is working as excpected. Both Tables (Table 1 and Table 2) has 80k rows but the Table Result has 500k rows. Why is this happening?

Comment: @ViníciusAffonso -   The full outer join is there so that if an `id` appears only in the first table, or only in the second, then it appears in the result. But that should give you no more than 160k rows, even if all the `id`'s had no overlaps between the two tables, **if the id is unique** in each table. Do you have more than one row per `id`, in either table? (If you do, the problem again doesn't make sense!)

Comment: I have only one ID per table and both tables have the exactly ids. The result should give me the same amount of rows than before

Comment: Nevermind. I was using the wrong id for the outer join. Now its working perfectly. Thx

Comment: @vini -  If all the id's are present in both tables, and you don't care if there are exceptions (they will not be in the result), then you can change the join to "inner join".